# find sum of values by month then find max sum of months

Tags: sql, database, oracle, max

I need to find the sum of values for each month and then find the max value for the months. I am a bit stumped and not sure what to do.

```
My customer wants it formatted a particular way:

Activity |  JUN  |  JUL  |  AUG  |  MIN  |   MAX  |  AVG
jogging  |  232  |   32  |  343  |   32  |   343  |  202 

Here is my table:

activity + status + date
____________________________
swimming +    1   + 13-DEC-02
swimming +    1   + 12-FEB-01
jogging  +    0   + 14-AUG-03
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN DECODE(TO_CHAR((TRUNC(date)), 'MON'),'JUL','JUL') IN 'JUL'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END ) JUL,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN DECODE(TO_CHAR((TRUNC(date)), 'MON'),'AUG','AUG') IN 'AUG'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END ) AUG
FROM daily_log
WHERE ACTIVITY_DESC IN ('Swimming','Jogging')
AND TRUNC(date) BETWEEN '01-JUL-2014' AND '30-JUN-2015'
AND STATUS = 1
group by ACTIVITY
```

Help!

Comment: This report have to show only JUN, JUL and AUG? What about other months and date intervals? Report will have only 3 months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is a bit too complicated. This, for example:

```
CASE
    WHEN DECODE(TO_CHAR((TRUNC(date)), 'MON'),'AUG','AUG') IN 'AUG'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

could be rewritten as:

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(date, 'MON') = 'AUG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

or even:

```
DECODE(TO_CHAR(date, 'MON'), 'AUG', 1, 0)
```

In other words, you need either `CASE` or `DECODE()` but not both. With that in mind, we can rewrite your query a bit:

```
SELECT activity
     , SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(date, 'MON'), 'JUL', 1, 0)) AS jul
     , SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(date, 'MON'), 'AUG', 1, 0)) AS aug
  FROM daily_log
 WHERE activity_desc IN ('Swimming','Jogging')
   AND date >= DATE'2014-07-01'
   AND date < DATE'2015-07-01'
   AND status = 1
GROUP BY activity;
```

Now, notice how I changed your filter on the `date` column (which, by the way, is an awful name for a column since `DATE` is an Oracle keyword, used for a data type and for ANSI date literals). You want to avoid using `TRUNC()` on a `DATE` column, especially if it is indexed (and if it isn't indexed, you might want to consider indexing it). Since you want the minimum and maximum values for all months, you'll want to use the `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions:

```
SELECT activity, jul, aug
     , LEAST(jul, aug) AS min
     , GREATEST(jul, aug) AS max
     , (jul+aug)/2 AS avg
  FROM (
    SELECT activity
         , SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(date, 'MON'), 'JUL', 1, 0)) AS jul
         , SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(date, 'MON'), 'AUG', 1, 0)) AS aug
      FROM daily_log
     WHERE activity_desc IN ('Swimming','Jogging')
       AND date >= DATE'2014-07-01'
       AND date < DATE'2015-07-01'
       AND status = 1
    GROUP BY activity
);
```

Unfortunately there is nothing like `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` that will compute an average value, so we have to do that by hand. You'll want to increase the denominator when adding results for additional months.

Comment: Wow. Many thanks for your answer. I'm a struggling sql noob..,Your help is much appreciated. I think you earned your karma for the day.

Answer (score 0):

For MIN/MAX you could use GREATEST and LEAST, if you just need to select values from the result.O you can use the MIN,MAX and AVG function to aggregate the values directly from the source data.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm

Also you might want to look into using subqueries, especially using the WITH-clause. To select intermediate results you can combine together.

http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php

Regarding the SUM(CASE bit, you might have access to PIVOT as an option for transforming rows to columns.

http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Edit:
Something like this should do it

```
SELECT Activity,
  COALESCE(AUG,0) AS AUG,
  COALESCE(JUN,0) AS JUN,
  COALESCE(JUL,0) AS JUL,
  MIN,MAX,AVG
FROM (
    SELECT
      Mon,
      Activity,
      Count, 
      MIN(Count) OVER (PARTITION BY Activity) AS Min,
      MAX(Count) OVER (PARTITION BY Activity) AS Max,
      AVG(Count) OVER (PARTITION BY Activity) AS Avg
    FROM (
      SELECT TO_CHAR("date",'MON') AS Mon, activity, COUNT(*) Count
      FROM daily_log
      GROUP BY TO_CHAR("date",'MON'), activity
    )
) PIVOT ( SUM(Count) FOR Mon IN ('AUG' AS AUG, 'JUN' AS JUN, 'JUL' AS JUL))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to aggregate twice: once to compute per-month rollups, and a second time to compute statistics over those rollups.  That requires (at minimum) two queries, one within the scope of the other as a common table expression, inline view, or subquery.  For example:

```
SELECT
  activity,
  SUM(
    CASE month
      WHEN 7 THEN count
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) JUL,
  SUM(
    CASE month
      WHEN 8 THEN count
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AUG,
  AVG(count) AS avg,
  MAX(count) AS max
FROM (
  SELECT
    activity,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "date") AS month,
    COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM daily_log
  WHERE
    ACTIVITY_DESC IN ('Swimming','Jogging')
    AND TRUNC("date") BETWEEN '01-JUL-2014' AND '30-JUN-2015'
    AND STATUS = 1
  group by ACTIVITY, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "date")
)
GROUP BY activity
```

Note that in your *real* query you will probably want to be more clever than `AVG(count)`, else you will get the wrong average in the event that there are zero entries in one or more months of interest.